# Is there difference between Process Control Block's program counter and CPU's program counter register?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, cpu

after CPU get fetched, CPU program counter value is incremented. at this time, Process control Block's program counter also get incremented? or they are not same and have some difference?

Comment: Why would the process/thread control block need to explicitly store the program counter - if the thread is not running, it's on the stack from the syscall/interrupt that entered the kernel?

Comment: Processes that are running use the CPU registers, while processes that are suspended use something like the PCB in memory to store their CPU state, whether suspended temporarily (and still runnable) or blocked on I/O (so not runnable).  This is how a single CPU can handle multiple processes.  The processes that are actually running use the CPU hardware directly and upon suspension, their CPU state is flushed to memory and potentially later restored (from memory to the CPU) for process resumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PCB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block) is a data structure in memory, not a register.  There's no mechanism for it to stay in sync with the CPU internal register automatically.  (except maybe on x86 with hardware task switching?)

The OS normally has to update manually, using the user-space context that an interrupt or exception saved.

Comment: PCB is used to store register values when cpu has to stop executing the process. is this right?

Comment: @niceyonom02: you *could* keep them there directly, but yes a PCB at least points at where they're stored.  Linux for example keeps them on the kernel stack for that task (thread or process), where the kernel entry point saved them.  I think in Linux, `struct task_struct` is what you'd call a PCB.  https://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/ds/ds.html / http://www.cs.albany.edu/~sdc/CSI500/Fal11/Classes/C01-C04/IntroTaskStructFields.html.  (task_struct does have a pointer to that saved register state so a debugger can use system calls to modify the registers of another process.)